# NullPointerException in HDFSStore.getMeta()

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, apache-storm

I am struck on a part

I was trying to execute an example code https://github.com/stormprocessor/storm-state/blob/master/src/jvm/storm/state/example/MapExample.java code of github.com/stormprocessor/storm-state. It uses HDFS.

but it is giving an NullPointerException as

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at storm.state.hdfs.HDFSStore.getMeta(HDFSStore.java:37)
    at storm.state.PartitionedState.getState(PartitionedState.java:11)
    at storm.state.bolt.StatefulBoltExecutor.prepare(StatefulBoltExecutor.java:36)
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__4052$fn__4061.invoke(executor.clj:610)
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__465.invoke(util.clj:375)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
```

in code of above link I have changed

```
 builder.setBolt("counter", new StatefulBoltExecutor(new WordCount(), new HDFSStore("hdfs://ip-10-202-7-99.ec2.internal:8020/tmp/data")), 8)
            .fieldsGrouping("spout", new Fields("word"));
```

to

```
 builder.setBolt("counter", new StatefulBoltExecutor(new WordCount(), new HDFSStore("hdfs://localhost:9000/home/mohit/hadoop/tmp/dfs/data")), 8)
```

which is my HDFS path.

Codes in error log are present at

https://github.com/stormprocessor/storm-state/blob/master/src/jvm/storm/state

Sorry for very less links, as I am a learning student with very less reputation,
Please Help, Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the error you are getting is because your namenode is not listening to port 9000 which you have configured in your given code. Try to verify the value of this property **fs.default.name** in your core-site.xml file and check which port your namenode is using. I think it could be 8020. If that is say 8020 then you code will be something as below.

builder.setBolt("counter", new StatefulBoltExecutor(new WordCount(), new HDFSStore("hdfs://localhost:**8020**/home/mohit/hadoop/tmp/dfs/data")), 8)

I hope this may solve your problem

Comment: Thank you for your  response, My port is 9000 in core-site.xml, after reading the answer I tried changing ports both in program and in core-site.xml to 8020, my namenode is working and hearing at port 8020. I conformed this by visiting localhost:50070 in browser. But same error is  there in log file.

Comment: I think you should try re-starting the cluster i.e all the daemon services and check if that works